# Spring MVC 3.0 + jsp footer

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm writing Sping MVC based application all my methods inside a controller return ModelAndView objects.

What I would like to do is to apply standard HTML footer on each JSP page, like signup/signin/about us/contact use/etc...
Is there any way I can do it within a controller? I know that I can use

```
<%@ include file="footer.jsp" %>
```

but I'm sure that there should be more elegant way to do that.

Comment: Could http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/ be a solution for you?

Comment: Maybe, but I'm interesting in some out of the box solution based on Spring MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is purely the responsibility of the view layer - the controllers should not know that the views have a common anything; the controllers only know the name of the view.

So how you can implement this depends entirely on which view-layer technology you use. If using JSP, you can simple include the footer.jsp in each jsp view, or use a tool like Sitemesh (which is great) to be able to capture common layouts in a single file. If using a template engine like Velocity, it's trivial to also set up common "layouts" which can capture the common logic - like the presence of a header, menu, footer etc - in a single place and then load the content template for each individual page.

Comment: Thanks too. @danny.lesnik, which way did you end up doing it?